# faster way to concatenate movie clips using moviepy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg, moviepy

By using Moviepy library i found a better way for making clips

```
 clip_1 = ffmpeg_extract_subclip(filename,
                       t1, t2,
                       targetname="test1.mp4")

rather than using VideoFileClip function

clip1 = VideoFileClip("test1.mp4")
```

However i was thinking if we could combine 2 or more video files with such a speed difference using any other methods other than

```
final_clip = CompositeVideoClip([clip1,clip2])
```

or remove the print functionality of the module to speed up the process??

Comment: do you only need to concatenate a list of clips ?

Comment: @Abhishek, did you manage to get this?

Comment: no i didnt find any better way but if used with python threading module on cloud gpu server it runs faster...

Comment: Hi @AbhishekAgarwal how did you speed up MoviePy on a cloud gpu server? I don't usually use Python so I'm not sure what you mean by a "python threading module"? I've tried running MoviePy on a AWS GPU optimised server but it's not runnning any faster.